# How read Chinese text from postgreSQL database using ado.net c#?

Tags: postgresql

Try to read the chinese text but did not succeed.

I have used Npgsql as a Provider and npgqsl.dll as dll
I have used ADO.NET NpgsqlConnection,NpgsqlCommand,NpgsqlDataReader and NpgsqlDataAdapter class objects.

I want to read the chinese text which is stored in table of postgreSQL database.

Anyone help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If your database has encoding `SQL_ASCII`, you are lost.

Other that that, set the [connection string parameter](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html) `Client Encoding` to the value your .NET application expects.